# Why the browser is ignoring new empty lines inside the textarea in HTML?

Tags: html, web, textarea

When I try to put text that has **multiple empty lines inside a textarea in HTML**, the browser ignores them  and does not display them. My purpose is to allow the user to edit his text while preserving all the new lines.

If I put this:

```
text a\n\n\ntext b\ntextc
```

The browser displays:

```
text a
text b
text c
```

My purpose:

```
text a


text b
text c
```

Answer (score 0):

This code adds "abc" with two line feeds after each to a text area.  This works in Chrome and in Edge.  It could be the browser you are using if you don't see the same.  And if you are still stuck, using div instead of textarea may work (div seems more friendly to me, I don't know why).  And as the other answer suggests, br sometimes works when slash-n does not.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function btnTest_Click() {
            var d = document.getElementById("txt1");
            d.innerHTML += 'abc\n\n';
        }
    </script>
    <div>
        <textarea id="txt1" rows="10" cols="25"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="test" onclick="btnTest_Click()" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Regarding the textarea, your solution allows to add two line feeds at the end of the text only. The problem is that when we save the text to the database and then put it back to the user so he can edit it, at this moment all empty lines will be ignored. As you may notice, those empty lines could be in the middle of the text as you can see in my question example. Unfortunately, using the div will generate a lot of tags therefore the text will take more space in the database which I am trying to avoid to be honest.

Comment: Test writing to and reading from your database when there are \n characters in the text.  Is that the source of your issue - it is not saving/reading \n characters correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you'd need to use a <br> tag for this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: The textarea render "<br>" as a simple text and not as a line break. To get a line break we have to use "\n".